# Search keyword from comma seperated values of tags in PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, tree

i am using moset tree, i am creating search functionality in which
when user enters keyword such as college, then  it should search in database with a value of college in tags column. if college matches then that entry should be displayed in result.

My Database View:
First Table: mt_links in which all the listing is saved.
Second Table: mt_cfvalues in which tags were saved and they were normalized
means in first and second table link_id is same. so we need to make relation with this column.

I created this query:

```
SELECT * FROM #__mt_links link INNER JOIN #__mt_cfvalues val
ON link.link_id = val.link_id AND val.value LIKE '%$keywords%'"
```

but in this way i am not getting all the results.

Tags Example: in mt_cfvalues table there is one column name as value which are keywords on the basis of which in need to get listing.

Example 1: college, university, institute
Example 2: repair, computer, laptop

if i enter any of keyword mentiond above eg: laptop which is third in listing then even i need to show that relative listing. means product in which laptop tags is used that product should be displayed as a result.

I hope i give clear information. please Help 
Thanks

Comment: CONCAT(laptop,value ) LIKE '%$keywords%' you can try this one it helpful u

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
   #__mt_links link 
   INNER JOIN #__mt_cfvalues val ON (
      link.link_id = val.link_id
   )
WHERE
   FIND_IN_SET(val.value,'$keywords') != 0
```

$keywords needs to look like : keyword1,keyword2,keyword3....,keywordN

Comment: it didn't work, here is what i am getting, i echo query

SELECT * FROM #__mt_links link INNER JOIN #__mt_cfvalues val ON ( link.link_id = val.link_id ) WHERE FIND_IN_SET(val.value,'college')

There are no results for your search query.

Comment: @user2753272: `Find_In_set` takes 2 arguments of which 1st is the value to be searched, and the 2nd is source in which search is to be performed. **Example**: `select .... find_in_set( '$keywords', val.value )`

Comment: Yes i tried the same with two arguments see:    
SELECT * FROM #__mt_links link INNER JOIN #__mt_cfvalues val ON link.link_id = val.link_id WHERE FIND_IN_SET('computer', val.value)
0 There are no results for your search query.

Comment: and i know that computer is in the value column. but still not able to get it.

Comment: if you search for computer and in the column it's like Computer it won't find it.